# React Intro tutorial: how do list's keys get their value?

Tags: reactjs

I have no experience with js and suggested to learn React before React Native. My question comes from code from [Intro to React's tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html).

In tutorial, we made a list named `history`, with `move` as its `key`.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
     this.state = {
      history: [{
        squares: Array(9).fill(null)
      }],
      xIsNext: true,
      stepNumber: 0,
    };
  }

  [...]

  render() {
    [...]

    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ?
        'Move #' + move :
        'Game start';
      return (
        <li key={move}>
          <a href="#" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</a>
        </li>
      );
    });

[...]
```

The explanation for that part was

> [...] React asks you to specify a key property on each element in a list, a string to differentiate each component from its siblings. In this case, alexa, ben, claudia might be sensible keys; if the items correspond to objects in a database, the database ID is usually a good choice:

```
<li key={user.id}>{user.name}: {user.taskCount} tasks left</li>
```

> [...] It's strongly recommended that you assign proper keys whenever you build dynamic lists. If you don't have an appropriate key handy, you may want to consider restructuring your data so that you do. [...] If you don't specify any key, React will warn you and fall back to using the array index as a key – [...]

Now what I'm confused about, what is `move` on `history` above? I can't see anything implying `move` is assigned a value, yet when it's printed, it shows list index? How come?

Comment: I'd strongly consider learning JS before trying to learn a framework that relies heavily on knowing JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list is being created by using a *map* method to 'map over' the *history* array. *map* will call a function for each element in the array; the second parameter to this callback function is the index of the element in the array.

In your code the callback function looks like this:

```
(step, move) => {
  const desc = move ?
    'Move #' + move :
    'Game start';
  return (
    <li key={move}>
      <a href="#" onClick={() => this.jumpTo(move)}>{desc}</a>
    </li>
  );
}
```

and therefore the index of the array, the second parameter, is called *move* (you could call it anything); the value of this is then rendered as they key property for each list item.

[Description of *map* here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: So... is step the `current value`? But just not used?

Comment: nvm finally I understand. Thank you very much, your explanation and link truly a big help!